# How to search/compare the integer of Column 1 in the list-type Column 2 in Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one dataframe like below - and I would like to test if Column `Number` is in the Column `List of Numbers` for each row record.

[image]

Eventually I would expect to get the `Result` Column as like below:

[image]

Is there any better way to get the expected result in Python Pandas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension with `in` statement:

```
df['Result'] = [b in a for a, b in df[['List of Numbers','Number']].values]
```

Similar idea with `zip`:

```
df['Result'] = [b in a for a, b in zip(df['List of Numbers'],df['Number'])]
```

Or solution with [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df['Result'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Number'] in x['List of Numbers'], axis=1)
```

EDIT: Change `df['Result']` to mask for any solutions above and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) :

```
mask = df.apply(lambda x: x['Number'] in x['List of Numbers'], axis=1)
df1 = df[mask]
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael: the `apply` function works pretty well! Thank you so much! I am also thinking if we can straightaway filter the rows if it is `True` instead of adding a `Result` column and then filter it (which would be still working by using `.loc` fo filter)?

Comment: This is great! very useful! Thank you so much!